# Hive - How to query a table to get its own name?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, lookup, lookup-tables

I want to write a query such that it returns the table name (of the table I am querying) and some other values. Something like:

```
select table_name, col1, col2 from table_name;
```

I need to do this in Hive. Any idea how I can get the table name of the table I am querying?

Basically, I am creating a lookup table that stores the table name and some other information on a daily basis in Hive. Since Hive does not (at least the version we are using) support full-fledged `INSERTs`, I am trying to use the workaround where we can `INSERT` into a table with a `SELECT` query that queries another table. Part of this involves actually storing the table name as well. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of my use case, this will suffice:

```
select 'table_name', col1, col2 from table_name;
```

It returns the table name with the other columns that I will require.